# Registering multiple change events using JS and Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events, onchange

I have a checkbox where I am registering change events differently on the element.
First is registered using `ng-change` directive of angular js.
Second is registered using `addEventListener` change event.

During runtime only angular's `ng-change` is triggered but not the function registered through JS.
I am thinking angular is removing the registered function.

Is there a way to trigger both at runtime.

Note : Can't move `ng-change` function to `addEventListener` scope as there are totally separate modules.

Comment: share your code  in jsfiddle so we can see your problem

Comment: If you are using both ng-change and addEventListener on the same element, there is a design issue in your code.